# Употребление фигурных скобок компилятором

Tags: c#

Любая конструкция `if` может быть записана с фигурными скобками или без них. К примеру:

```
bool j = true;
if(j==true)
    MessageBox.Show("That's true")
```

Или же так:

```
bool j = true;
if(j==true)
{
   MessageBox.Show("That's true")
}
```

Разговор идет только конструкции `if` с единственным действием.
Отсюда несколько вопросов:

1. Игнорирует ли компилятор эти скобки?
2. Если нет, обращает ли внимание программа на них?
3. Оказывают ли влияние эти скобки на быстродействие программы (хоть самую незначительную)?

Comment: На ошибку с незакрытой кавычкой точно обратит внимание компилятор

Comment: Бывает)Исправил.

Comment: ты определись: цикл или if? Разницы конечно нет, но нужно чтобы текст был релевантен коду

Comment: По факту я имею в виду все.И циклы и условные конструкции.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.docx)

Для `if statement`

```
if_statement:
    | 'if' '(' boolean_expression ')' embedded_statement
    | 'if' '(' boolean_expression ')' embedded_statement 'else' embedded_statement
    ;
```

Для циклов. например while:

```
while_statement:
    | 'while' '(' boolean_expression ')' embedded_statement
    ;
```

Как можно заметить на уровне спецификации никаких скобочек нет.

В свою очередь `embedded_statement` раскрывается так:

```
embedded_statement:
    | block
    | empty_statement
    | expression_statement
    | selection_statement
    | iteration_statement
    | jump_statement
    | try_statement
    | checked_statement
    | unchecked_statement
    | lock_statement
    | using_statement
    | yield_statement
    | embedded_statement_unsafe
    ;
```

И скобочки в данном случае являются частью `block`

```
block:
    | '{' statement_list? '}'
    ;
```

Таким образом, можно сказать, что:

1. Компилятор скобки не игнорирует, так как они являются частью синтаксической конструкции
2. сама программа на них не может обращать внимания, но отличие в использовании все-таки есть. Например: внутри блока можно определять переменные, без скобок - нет.
3. Так как это чисто синтаксическая конструкция на быстродействие скобки никакого влияния не оказывают.

Answer (score 10):

Компилятор эти скобки не игнорирует, а просто позволяет нам их либо писать, либо не писать. Грубо говоря, когда он разбирает текст программы в абстрактное синтаксическое дерево, то не зависимо от наличия или отсутствия скобок, структура дерева полученного в результате будет одна и та же.

Таким образом, даже на уровне абстрактного дерева, которое еще не совсем программа, этих скобок уже не существует. Поэтому, независимо от того, каким образом выполняется код, можно смело утверждать что программа на эти скобки внимание не обращает, и влияние на время выполнения программы они не оказывают.

Answer (score 5):

1. Компилятор и первый вариант, и второй компилирует в один и тот же msil код (с настроенным параметром "оптимизированный код", который по умолчанию в режиме релиза)
2. Внутри программы после компиляции нет скобок. Грубо говоря там просто непрерывная последовательность команд с каким-то аналогом goto (условным и безусловным)
3. Не оказывает даже незначительного влияния

**UPD**

В конфигурации отладки на каждую фигурную скобку добавляется nop-код в msil'е и nop-инструкция в нативном коде. Делается это, как было замечено в комментариях, для удобства отладки

Comment: Только не забывайте, что в релизе надо запускать не под отладчиком, а цепляться к уже запущенной программе, и обязательно после того, как jit прошел по классу. Потому что если вы просто запустите релиз под отладкой, по f5 - jit заметит отладчик и навставляет нопов ради вашего удобства (чтобы дать вам возможность поставить брекпойнт на закрывающей скобке). Судя по вашему апдейту - именно эти нопы вы и видите

Comment: Вот по теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070817-00/?p=25533. Вы уверены, что вы правильно приаттачили отладчик?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53166/discussion-on-answer-by-qutrix----).

Comment: **добавляет nop с каждой фигурной скобкой.** а можно какие то выкладки?

Comment: да, уже сам посмотрел. действительно добавляет. Очень и очень интересно.

Comment: @KoVadim, а чат зайди, там есть предположения почему

Comment: в чаты не хожу:)

Comment: @KoVadim а вот я злобно восстановлю свое сообщение о настоящей причине появления nop-ов, и пусть ваши комментарии выглядят странно

Comment: @KoVadim, в конфиге релиза все ок - нет там nop'ов (дополнил ответ)